# Extend cropVariants from sitepackage

Tags: typo3, fluid-styled-content

Typo3 v12 with fluid_styled_content.

I would like to define a custom cropVariant without overwriting the default cropVariant. The reason I want to do that is to use the `<f:image>` view helper to load an optimally sized square preview of an image.

I thought this would work:

`local_packages/mysitepackage/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/sys_file_reference.php`:

```php
<?php
defined('TYPO3') or die('Access denied.');

call_user_func(function() {
    $GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['columns']['crop']['config']['cropVariants']['square'] = [
        'title' => 'square',
        'allowedAspectRatios' => [
            '1:1' => [
                'title' => '1:1',
                'value' => 1.0
            ],
        ],
        'selectedRatio' => '1:1',
        'cropArea' => [
            'x' => 0.0,
            'y' => 0.0,
            'width' => 1.0,
            'height' => 1.0,
        ],
    ];
});
```

--> but this sadly overwrites the default cropVariant.

Additional info:

- I tried merging it with the preexisting `['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['columns']['crop']['config']['cropVariants']`, but it is not defined (yet) at the point in time my TCA override function is called.
- I managed to hard code the [original default cropVariant](https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/db1408d90d8b62df2b86116af55163ffcab9362b/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/Element/ImageManipulationElement.php#L52) into my file to preserve it but obviously I would rather extend the cropVariants dynamically for future proofing reasons.
- the linked source code mentions cropVariantcollections, but I could not find information about that in the docs.

Any help or hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Short answer

Nope, it's not possible to keep the default if custom crop variants on `sys_file_reference` level are defined. See below for the long answer and variant **1. generic on sys_file_reference level**.

That means, you need to define it manually or define cropVariants on contentElement / field level (see also long answer below).

## Long Answer - Introduction

There are basically two ways to define cropVariants:

1. generic on `sys_file_reference` level
2. as override for specific content element(s)

### 1. generic on `sys_file_reference` level

The code you provide is basically the way to define cropVariants **globally** for all file references.

That is documented here:

- main: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CropVariants/General/Index.html
- 12.4: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/12.4/en-us/ApiOverview/CropVariants/General/Index.html

The point is, that as soon as some extensions defines cropVariants on that level, the `default` cropVariant is removed. Following code is responsible for this:

```php
// see: https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/db1408d90d8b62df2b86116af55163ffcab9362b/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/Element/ImageManipulationElement.php#L228-L231

// If ratios are set do not add default options
if (isset($baseConfiguration['cropVariants'])) {
    unset($defaultConfig['cropVariants']);
}
```

That is by intention. That means, you need to additionally set the "default" by your own, copy&paste it as default variant in your override file from here:
https://github.com/TYPO3/typo3/blob/db1408d90d8b62df2b86116af55163ffcab9362b/typo3/sysext/backend/Classes/Form/Element/ImageManipulationElement.php#L48-L85

A simplyfied example without pre-existing check from other extensions and overrides:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['sys_file_reference']['columns']['crop'] = [
  'config' => [
    'cropVariants' => [
        'default' => [
            'title' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.crop_variant.default',
            'allowedAspectRatios' => [
                '16:9' => [
                    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.ratio.16_9',
                    'value' => 16 / 9,
                ],
                '3:2' => [
                    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.ratio.3_2',
                    'value' => 3 / 2,
                ],
                '4:3' => [
                    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.ratio.4_3',
                    'value' => 4 / 3,
                ],
                '1:1' => [
                    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.ratio.1_1',
                    'value' => 1.0,
                ],
                'NaN' => [
                    'title' => 'LLL:EXT:core/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_wizards.xlf:imwizard.ratio.free',
                    'value' => 0.0,
                ],
            ],
            'selectedRatio' => 'NaN',
            'cropArea' => [
                'x' => 0.0,
                'y' => 0.0,
                'width' => 1.0,
                'height' => 1.0,
            ],
        ], // default
        'square' => [
            'title' => 'square',
            'allowedAspectRatios' => [
                '1:1' => [
                    'title' => '1:1',
                    'value' => 1.0
                ],
            ],
            'selectedRatio' => '1:1',
            'cropArea' => [
                'x' => 0.0,
                'y' => 0.0,
                'width' => 1.0,
                'height' => 1.0,
            ],
        ], // square
    ], // cropVariants
  ], // config
];
```

### 2. as override for specific content element(s)

If you want to override or set the cropVariants on per contentElement or field level, here is the link to the documentation for that variant:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/CropVariants/ContentElement/Index.html

Here, you do not need to redefine the "default" variant, if not removed. But you can "append/change" it per content element or event disable some.

The feature needed here is called `overrideChildTca`. Here an example taken from the documentation for the `textmexia` content element and the `assets` field - just with your cropVariant instead of the example from the documentation:

```php
$GLOBALS['TCA']['tt_content']['types']['textmedia']['columnsOverrides']['assets']['config']['overrideChildTca']['columns']['crop']['config'] = [
    'cropVariants' => [
       'default' => [
           'disabled' => true,
       ],
       'square' => [
            'title' => 'square',
            'allowedAspectRatios' => [
                '1:1' => [
                    'title' => '1:1',
                    'value' => 1.0
                ],
            ],
            'selectedRatio' => '1:1',
            'cropArea' => [
                'x' => 0.0,
                'y' => 0.0,
                'width' => 1.0,
                'height' => 1.0,
            ],
       ],
    ],
];
```

Comment: It would make sense to give https://github.com/josefglatz/cropvariantsbuilder a try If you are using crop variants extensively in your project/s. It is just a wrapper around the TYPO3 core features around crop variants

Comment: Thanks a lot! This cleared things up for me.